# JavaScript Detecting NULL value in String

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, null

Im trying to make an if statement where x,y,z, all return empty, then in my logic r should="", so the program won´t enter the if statement below. The problem is that it seems that its adding the "" 3 times to the r, making its length 3,  any idea on how to solve it?

If I put r.length>3 for example it works

```
  var r="";
var r+=x();
var r+=y();
var r+=z();

if(r!=""||r.length==0){
 alert("something");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of r.length?

Comment: I think that r.length is suppose to be how many characters in that string

Comment: Please do not post code which doesn't run, i.e. generates console errors. Fix those first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a little ambiguous.... so I hope this helps:

If `r` is an array it would look like this:

```
var r=[];
r.push(x());
r.push(y());
r.push(z()); 

if(r.length === 0){
   alert("something");
}
```

FYI `I += thing` is the same as `I = I + thing`. Plus is not suitable for arrays OR strings.

The syntax is `String.concat()` or `Array.push()`

Comment: (I copy and pasted the OP's code) ... But yes, you are very correct XD